# Underclocking Intel Core Duo/disabling turbo mode (Intel Dynamic Acceleration)

Tags: windows-7, intel-core2, turbo-boost, underclock

Since some microcode update I get turbo mode in my Core 2 Duo - CPU reports the speeds highier then nominal and powertop denotes it as "Turbo Mode" (despite I could find information about "Turbo Mode" on Intel pages only for i3/i5/i7). Having processor in "Turbo Mode" makes my laptop overheat.

I know how to force underclocking in Linux but is it possible to disable turbo mode/lower the maximum clock on Windows?

**EDIT**: Previously it was called  [Intel Dynamic Acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Dynamic_Acceleration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In control panel in `Power Options` -> `Edit power plan` -> `Change advanced power settings` -> `Processor power management` -> `Maximum processor state`. I set it to <100% and it seems to work.